# Chrome failing to connect to websocket server (Opcode -1) "handshake was canceled"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ssl, networking, websocket

I have a secure websocket server using a self-signed certificate that I'm not able to connect to from a chrome (v44.0.2403.107) client. Its my test server, and its created using pretty near identical code to my app server - which I *can* connect to.

I've tried restarting chrome. I've tried restarting my VM and all my putty instances. I know the port is correct because I can debug to the point in my server where the port is used, and I see that its 8090. I can do the same in my client: 8090. When i set a breakpoint at the callback in my server that's supposed to receive a websocket connection request, it never gets hit. The exact same breakpoint in my app server *does* get hit, so I've ruled out debugging issues.

The error I'm receiving in the console when it fails to connect is: `WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:8090/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled`. I'm also seeing only one frame in the network tab for that connection: `(Opcode -1) Length: 40 17:06:08.360` and then of course I get a websocket error event that contains no additional useful info. What does Opcode -1 mean?

Here is the output I get from tcpdump on the VM-side, verifying that I am in fact getting network traffic from my browser to my VM (I set a breakpoint right before creating the WebSocket handle, and only when I press go does all this stuff happen):

```
[vagrant@localhost temp]$ sudo tcpdump -nnXSs 0 'port 8090'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
14:57:40.023027 IP 10.0.2.2.54174 > 10.0.2.15.8090: Flags [S], seq 133632001, win 65535, options [mss 1460], length 0
        0x0000:  4500 002c bd91 0000 4006 a52a 0a00 0202  E..,....@..*....
        0x0010:  0a00 020f d39e 1f9a 07f7 1001 0000 0000  ................
        0x0020:  6002 ffff 74e5 0000 0204 05b4            `...t.......
14:57:40.023066 IP 10.0.2.15.8090 > 10.0.2.2.54174: Flags [S.], seq 4249375587, ack 133632002, win 14600, options [mss 1460], length 0
        0x0000:  4500 002c 0000 4000 4006 22bc 0a00 020f  E..,..@.@.".....
        0x0010:  0a00 0202 1f9a d39e fd48 5363 07f7 1002  .........HSc....
        0x0020:  6012 3908 eb1f 0000 0204 05b4            `.9.........
14:57:40.023608 IP 10.0.2.2.54174 > 10.0.2.15.8090: Flags [.], ack 4249375588, win 65535, length 0
        0x0000:  4500 0028 bd92 0000 4006 a52d 0a00 0202  E..(....@..-....
        0x0010:  0a00 020f d39e 1f9a 07f7 1002 fd48 5364  .............HSd
        0x0020:  5010 ffff 3be5 0000                      P...;...
14:57:40.023636 IP 10.0.2.2.54174 > 10.0.2.15.8090: Flags [P.], seq 133632002:133632175, ack 4249375588, win 65535, length 173
        0x0000:  4500 00d5 bd93 0000 4006 a47f 0a00 0202  E.......@.......
        0x0010:  0a00 020f d39e 1f9a 07f7 1002 fd48 5364  .............HSd
        0x0020:  5018 ffff 76a5 0000 1603 0100 a801 0000  P...v...........
        0x0030:  a403 03b3 155b 57a9 66a3 71d9 859a 748d  .....[W.f.q...t.
        0x0040:  55d3 9f95 12c8 69cd bf8b 96f2 dde4 f936  U.....i........6
        0x0050:  32b5 5c00 0022 c02b c02f 009e cc14 cc13  2.\..".+./......
        0x0060:  cc15 c00a c014 0039 c009 c013 0033 009c  .......9.....3..
        0x0070:  0035 002f 000a 00ff 0100 0059 0000 000e  .5./.......Y....
        0x0080:  000c 0000 096c 6f63 616c 686f 7374 0017  .....localhost..
        0x0090:  0000 0023 0000 000d 0016 0014 0601 0603  ...#............
        0x00a0:  0501 0503 0401 0403 0301 0303 0201 0203  ................
        0x00b0:  0005 0005 0100 0000 0033 7400 0000 1200  .........3t.....
        0x00c0:  0075 5000 0000 0b00 0201 0000 0a00 0600  .uP.............
        0x00d0:  0400 1700 18                             .....
14:57:40.023646 IP 10.0.2.15.8090 > 10.0.2.2.54174: Flags [.], ack 133632175, win 15544, length 0
        0x0000:  4500 0028 dcea 4000 4006 45d5 0a00 020f  E..(..@.@.E.....
        0x0010:  0a00 0202 1f9a d39e fd48 5364 07f7 10af  .........HSd....
        0x0020:  5010 3cb8 fe7f 0000                      P.<.....
14:57:40.025597 IP 10.0.2.15.8090 > 10.0.2.2.54174: Flags [P.], seq 4249375588:4249376372, ack 133632175, win 15544, length 784
        0x0000:  4500 0338 dceb 4000 4006 42c4 0a00 020f  E..8..@.@.B.....
        0x0010:  0a00 0202 1f9a d39e fd48 5364 07f7 10af  .........HSd....
        0x0020:  5018 3cb8 1b3b 0000 1603 0300 4b02 0000  P.<..;......K...
        0x0030:  4703 03a3 0a5c dd01 39a5 c7e6 33de 6e10  G....\..9...3.n.
        0x0040:  1eb4 d7c3 1127 d7a0 7beb bac2 fbd0 5dc6  .....'..{.....].
        0x0050:  3c75 3200 009c 0000 1fff 0100 0100 0023  <u2............#
        0x0060:  0000 3374 0012 0868 7474 702f 312e 3108  ..3t...http/1.1.
        0x0070:  6874 7470 2f31 2e30 1603 0302 b20b 0002  http/1.0........
        0x0080:  ae00 02ab 0002 a830 8202 a430 8201 8c02  .......0...0....
        0x0090:  0900 d437 88ae 7bbe 1e4d 300d 0609 2a86  ...7..{..M0...*.
        0x00a0:  4886 f70d 0101 0505 0030 1431 1230 1006  H........0.1.0..
        0x00b0:  0355 0403 0c09 6c6f 6361 6c68 6f73 7430  .U....localhost0
        0x00c0:  1e17 0d31 3530 3131 3030 3932 3530 315a  ...150110092501Z
        0x00d0:  170d 3235 3031 3037 3039 3235 3031 5a30  ..250107092501Z0
        0x00e0:  1431 1230 1006 0355 0403 0c09 6c6f 6361  .1.0...U....loca
        0x00f0:  6c68 6f73 7430 8201 2230 0d06 092a 8648  lhost0.."0...*.H
        0x0100:  86f7 0d01 0101 0500 0382 010f 0030 8201  .............0..
        0x0110:  0a02 8201 0100 dd4e 94f0 608c 3bc9 d7a7  .......N..`.;...
        0x0120:  cc5b 0135 5630 4b45 5e01 c08f c543 66c1  .[.5V0KE^....Cf.
        0x0130:  d581 dba0 ce59 ccd4 5e63 f4a5 4dab 88cf  .....Y..^c..M...
        0x0140:  fafc ade0 bd7e 640f e690 21f0 2c7e de6a  .....~d...!.,~.j
        0x0150:  5342 990e 3f8e e227 b8e3 f133 b320 f1e1  SB..?..'...3....
        0x0160:  2b1d 7225 7103 ca7f e286 026c 1d2c 5b4f  +.r%q......l.,[O
        0x0170:  71ad 21c5 c10f b686 9c59 873c 89db fe7d  q.!......Y.<...}
        0x0180:  1a96 9c65 9fcd db51 87db f7c2 795b e338  ...e...Q....y[.8
        0x0190:  2bc5 2c93 c74d aa79 487d d3b8 5c4e 3919  +.,..M.yH}..\N9.
        0x01a0:  a5eb 1665 6778 050c cba8 a770 6324 8f07  ...egx.....pc$..
        0x01b0:  228c 6084 ac91 5d57 9569 b0a1 aaed 62a5  ".`...]W.i....b.
        0x01c0:  6f82 0afd 3d81 0f1b e4c0 55da 674e 8cde  o...=.....U.gN..
        0x01d0:  252b 3b35 2891 6d40 bc23 ac66 8e24 4dda  %+;5(.m@.#.f.$M.
        0x01e0:  fc59 5f1d 0c5f ad21 6c00 6ce5 6ed0 f6f8  .Y_.._.!l.l.n...
        0x01f0:  8752 a2b8 3758 a79c 4898 1cd4 3e51 8e33  .R..7X..H...>Q.3
        0x0200:  5d9b 5142 8ace d055 59da 4447 5cac d464  ].QB...UY.DG\..d
        0x0210:  dd9c 91fb 4499 0203 0100 0130 0d06 092a  ....D......0...*
        0x0220:  8648 86f7 0d01 0105 0500 0382 0101 0054  .H.............T
        0x0230:  e877 2716 fedc c2ac a79e fc8b 765e f38b  .w'.........v^..
        0x0240:  96b2 e52d 60bb 85ec 9ffc 13ba b4a3 2500  ...-`.........%.
        0x0250:  ac52 607b 3ea6 4ce1 693d 200e 7982 a586  .R`{>.L.i=..y...
        0x0260:  ed96 ab27 a129 009c d6bc f1f4 34bd 4b22  ...'.)......4.K"
        0x0270:  34ad 093c 9754 a465 2226 3c60 7f34 0f07  4..<.T.e"&<`.4..
        0x0280:  a069 e518 e9e8 3134 4a16 f9d6 0a60 6ed5  .i....14J....`n.
        0x0290:  2f41 3192 f40b ed47 c5a6 4e42 5ef0 22f8  /A1....G..NB^.".
        0x02a0:  b56b 6f59 5ecf 8eff 2da0 01e5 ab3c 8be0  .koY^...-....<..
        0x02b0:  ff5a d9fa 8468 f7ac 776b e387 09ec c965  .Z...h..wk.....e
        0x02c0:  ebee b6bd 5535 c5f0 ce47 1eef ddc4 f298  ....U5...G......
        0x02d0:  933c 9c9f 73dd e2c9 a5c2 d771 1bb9 6d83  .<..s......q..m.
        0x02e0:  8955 8104 46f1 d567 b28b 1694 25ea 4a54  .U..F..g....%.JT
        0x02f0:  df64 0524 7d8e 2c37 5314 b59f f268 ffdd  .d.$}.,7S....h..
        0x0300:  c946 444b 6f97 839f 8cfd 6b07 0018 ccbb  .FDKo.....k.....
        0x0310:  f4dc 3261 5367 e322 7f7d 2cb8 dd40 5788  ..2aSg.".},..@W.
        0x0320:  8532 2c45 2465 3daf e32d 49fa 9a98 3e16  .2,E$e=..-I...>.
        0x0330:  0303 0004 0e00 0000                      ........
14:57:40.026734 IP 10.0.2.2.54174 > 10.0.2.15.8090: Flags [.], ack 4249376372, win 65535, length 0
        0x0000:  4500 0028 bd95 0000 4006 a52a 0a00 0202  E..(....@..*....
        0x0010:  0a00 020f d39e 1f9a 07f7 10af fd48 5674  .............HVt
        0x0020:  5010 ffff 3828 0000                      P...8(..
14:57:40.028177 IP 10.0.2.2.54174 > 10.0.2.15.8090: Flags [P.], seq 133632175:133632558, ack 4249376372, win 65535, length 383
        0x0000:  4500 01a7 bd98 0000 4006 a3a8 0a00 0202  E.......@.......
        0x0010:  0a00 020f d39e 1f9a 07f7 10af fd48 5674  .............HVt
        0x0020:  5018 ffff c6ac 0000 1603 0301 0610 0001  P...............
        0x0030:  0201 009e 4509 3c23 b3ed 5828 9582 0362  ....E.<#..X(...b
        0x0040:  bdd7 046a 0410 38af 711c 8fca 0cfd 36f4  ...j..8.q.....6.
        0x0050:  3da0 c5c7 165a fedb 7f22 4063 2682 989f  =....Z..."@c&...
        0x0060:  1c20 f2ff b768 ee7e a30b 95e5 31d7 fa32  .....h.~....1..2
        0x0070:  58da a10f afe1 4391 c503 d624 3fa8 10e4  X.....C....$?...
        0x0080:  5151 0c15 cfbd 22c7 e7ca df5f ec40 e310  QQ...."...._.@..
        0x0090:  988f f1dc 56ac 6ec2 1edf fe6c eccc 2e70  ....V.n....l...p
        0x00a0:  d9b9 1ed2 a2f3 16c7 9e5a d563 fcf5 678f  .........Z.c..g.
        0x00b0:  9a01 27f5 6bee 356e 7b4d dd71 871e 3f85  ..'.k.5n{M.q..?.
        0x00c0:  59d6 c928 7d10 07cb 5997 e56c ba12 6e1b  Y..(}...Y..l..n.
        0x00d0:  ae89 02d3 5af8 9480 d6d1 800b 3481 c011  ....Z.......4...
        0x00e0:  b36b f634 00a2 57f2 5d7e 8da7 3ac6 3bbf  .k.4..W.]~..:.;.
        0x00f0:  bc9f 12f9 9c88 8ee6 3dda 1f75 9a1d dd82  ........=..u....
        0x0100:  689b 1291 7d98 d951 f09f ef59 df21 f692  h...}..Q...Y.!..
        0x0110:  f708 e488 7228 bfb5 6d4b 75ac 7c1b e3bc  ....r(..mKu.|...
        0x0120:  efe9 54f0 f821 1f2c bb41 3d38 0e4c 5bd1  ..T..!.,.A=8.L[.
        0x0130:  8af7 9214 0303 0001 0116 0303 003c 0000  .............<..
        0x0140:  0000 0000 0000 7539 a08c 45e4 a57d 2f5c  ......u9..E..}/\
        0x0150:  b4e0 6e98 53f4 8359 528d a430 89f0 2587  ..n.S..YR..0..%.
        0x0160:  4490 9d71 b4f2 6cfb fdc3 40e8 501a cb31  D..q..l...@.P..1
        0x0170:  3cad caf9 926b bd81 55a3 1603 0300 2800  <....k..U.....(.
        0x0180:  0000 0000 0000 019e 8daf 7add 6932 9aeb  ..........z.i2..
        0x0190:  e2ab aa26 27bc a925 43cd bc50 7516 e69d  ...&'..%C..Pu...
        0x01a0:  ea9f 3521 ba4c 34                        ..5!.L4
14:57:40.037113 IP 10.0.2.15.8090 > 10.0.2.2.54174: Flags [P.], seq 4249376372:4249376614, ack 133632558, win 16616, length 242
        0x0000:  4500 011a dcec 4000 4006 44e1 0a00 020f  E.....@.@.D.....
        0x0010:  0a00 0202 1f9a d39e fd48 5674 07f7 122e  .........HVt....
        0x0020:  5018 40e8 191d 0000 1603 0300 ba04 0000  P.@.............
        0x0030:  b600 0001 2c00 b03e 32e8 5f5d eead 8fd8  ....,..>2._]....
        0x0040:  7d30 19f4 9cee 907f a498 259f fd4c c87a  }0........%..L.z
        0x0050:  8e0b 8783 564b 7ce1 de37 b8ac 7bd3 3415  ....VK|..7..{.4.
        0x0060:  7f69 dece 4b60 a4eb ffcb 8781 1cfa 5930  .i..K`........Y0
        0x0070:  68e0 ab94 674a 5539 25b1 e8de 5a41 c93a  h...gJU9%...ZA.:
        0x0080:  6a3e c1e0 18b0 0e27 9207 6309 194c d7e0  j>.....'..c..L..
        0x0090:  a46b 191b 8a8e e1ec 40b6 2096 4458 f412  .k......@...DX..
        0x00a0:  52ad f44f 9f7c 6338 abea ba96 13e8 9c8c  R..O.|c8........
        0x00b0:  4a53 9c61 409e b121 de4d bafa bf88 f88e  JS.a@..!.M......
        0x00c0:  c7c2 0514 6905 0a5b 1f91 e155 bcae 0b82  ....i..[...U....
        0x00d0:  0d17 9ef7 2c05 a799 7408 51ac 957b f506  ....,...t.Q..{..
        0x00e0:  50d3 a841 0c9b 0314 0303 0001 0116 0303  P..A............
        0x00f0:  0028 e48b 22a4 e702 10f6 8f82 1c47 97fa  .(.."........G..
        0x0100:  990f 3697 3b44 9de5 9f5e 22f8 05a4 39b3  ..6.;D...^"...9.
        0x0110:  4762 e460 67c0 f142 9ddb                 Gb.`g..B..
14:57:40.037663 IP 10.0.2.2.54174 > 10.0.2.15.8090: Flags [.], ack 4249376614, win 65535, length 0
        0x0000:  4500 0028 bd9d 0000 4006 a522 0a00 0202  E..(....@.."....
        0x0010:  0a00 020f d39e 1f9a 07f7 122e fd48 5766  .............HWf
        0x0020:  5010 ffff 35b7 0000                      P...5...
14:57:40.039110 IP 10.0.2.2.54174 > 10.0.2.15.8090: Flags [F.], seq 133632558, ack 4249376614, win 65535, length 0
        0x0000:  4500 0028 bd9e 0000 4006 a521 0a00 0202  E..(....@..!....
        0x0010:  0a00 020f d39e 1f9a 07f7 122e fd48 5766  .............HWf
        0x0020:  5011 ffff 35b6 0000                      P...5...
14:57:40.039598 IP 10.0.2.15.8090 > 10.0.2.2.54174: Flags [F.], seq 4249376614, ack 133632559, win 16616, length 0
        0x0000:  4500 0028 dced 4000 4006 45d2 0a00 020f  E..(..@.@.E.....
        0x0010:  0a00 0202 1f9a d39e fd48 5766 07f7 122f  .........HWf.../
        0x0020:  5011 40e8 f4cc 0000                      P.@.....
14:57:40.040616 IP 10.0.2.2.54174 > 10.0.2.15.8090: Flags [.], ack 4249376615, win 65535, length 0
        0x0000:  4500 0028 bda0 0000 4006 a51f 0a00 0202  E..(....@.......
        0x0010:  0a00 020f d39e 1f9a 07f7 122f fd48 5767  .........../.HWg
        0x0020:  5010 ffff 35b5 0000                      P...5...
```

Any ideas as to how I can debug this further?

*Update:* After switching back to code I know has worked before, the problem still exists. So seems like I can rule out an issue with my code - is this a problem with my machine, network interfaces?

**Update2:** Its *still* happening even after I restarted my entire machine. Now i'm getting a little pissed off because this is actually going to block me from working. I really thought the problem would probably disappear (at least for a while) after restarting..

**Update3:** I created a node client that can successfully connect to the websocket server. So it seems to be a chrome issue. It certainly looks similar to what you see when it rejects the self-signed cert - but I'm using the same cert for my test server and app server. One works, the other doesn't, so it can't be the cert, right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok after long last I figured out something that worked. The problem still makes no sense to me, but the solution was to explicitly import the certificate into its accepted list in a very specific way:

1. Open an https page with the certificate
2. Click the lock icon and under `Connection` choose `Certificate Information`
3. Go to the `Details tab > Copy to File`. Choose `PKCS #7, single certificate` as the file format and save it somewhere (name doesn't matter).
4. Open up `Chrome Settings > Show advanced settings > HTTPS/SSL > Manage Certificates`.
5. Go to the `Trusted Certificate Root Authorities` tab
6. Import the certificate you "copied to file" in step 3
7. Restart Chrome (one of those few cases where you need to)

Thanks to the answer here:
[Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate#comment33762412_15076602)

Comment: Helpfull answer :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, there appear to be situations where this doesn't work.